# How do I overwrite a lazy service?

Tags: 8, caching

I'm trying to have my D8 site use Memcache for the lock service backend instead of using MySQL which is the default.

In `core.services.yml` we have the lock defintions:

```
  lock:
    class: Drupal\Core\Lock\DatabaseLockBackend
    arguments: ['@database']
    tags:
      - { name: backend_overridable }
    lazy: true
  lock.persistent:
    class: Drupal\Core\Lock\PersistentDatabaseLockBackend
    arguments: ['@database']
    tags:
      - { name: backend_overridable }
    lazy: true
```

In my site's `default.services.yml` I have this:

```
services:
  # Replaces the default lock backend with a memcache implementation.
  lock:
    class: Drupal\Core\Lock\LockBackendInterface
    factory: ['@memcache.lock.factory', get]
```

But when I obtain the `lock` service via `\Drupal::service('lock');`, I get a class `Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Lock\DatabaseLockBackend` returned instead of an instance of `Drupal\memcache\Lock\MemcacheLockBackend`. So my override did not work.

Unfortunately there's no documentation in the D8 memcache module for doing this, I'm just kind of winging it.

Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that the original service is lazy loaded?

Comment: see \Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderBase its a magic class so you have to look for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

default.services.yml is just basically just documentation/ an example, it's not actually loaded, at least not by default.

To load a services.yml file, it either needs to be named services.yml, or you need to explicitly added to the settings.php file, see example.settings.local.php and how it loads development services.

The redis module also provides implementations for those services, and it does so by providing a separate example.services.yml file that you can either include directly or copy and customize. That definitely works, I wrote and tested it.

Comment: Ah, indeed it does work. After trying again things are behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is the best way to do this; this is an alternative.

#### src/MyCustomModuleServiceProvider.php

```
namespace Drupal\my_custom_module;

use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class MyCustomModuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    $definition = new Definition('Drupal\Core\Lock\LockBackendInterface');
    $definition->setFactory([new Reference('memcache.lock.factory'), 'get']);

    $container->setDefinition('lock', $definition);

    $definition = new Definition('Drupal\Core\Lock\LockBackendInterface');
    $definition->setFactory([new Reference('memcache.lock.factory'), 'getPersistent']);

    $container->setDefinition('lock.persistent', $definition);
  }

}
```

Note [the naming of the class is special](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services) so that Drupal will automatically detect it: It is required to be a camel-case version of your module's machine name followed by *ServiceProvider*.